# Anyone play 5.1 DVD's through their Macbook Pro/Mbox Pro?

Tags: 5.1, surround-sound, macbook-pro, mbox, movies

Just wondering if it possible to listen in surround using Apples' DVD Player on my Macbook Pro through an Mbox Pro. Or would I need an external DVD player? Before I buy the Mbox Pro I wanted to make sure I can listen to other movies through it, not just my own work.

At the same time, can I send the video through a Blackmagic card to an external LCD TV? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I don't have an Mbox Pro myself, but I have successfully played back 5.1 sound from a variety of movies through several multi-channel audio interfaces. The trick is to configure which output of the audio interface represents which surround channel.

You do this by opening 'Audio Midi Setup' (it's in Applications>Utilities), and then, in the audio window, hit the button 'Configure Speakers...' and assign the correct Multichannel configuration.

Then any media player (including the DVD player application) that can handle 5.1 audio will send it out using that channel assignment (make sure the correct audio tracks are selected, sometimes the media player will default to stereo).

Comment: awesome i never would have found the "configure speakers" option. cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Yes. However Apple's DVD Player cannot play 5.1. VLC can though.

Comment: hmmm but it says this in the DVD player manual "DVD Player can play the audio from a DVD on digital audio equipment, such as a home theater system that plays 5.1 audio."

Comment: Perhaps this means you can output the (un-decoded) Dolby or DTS digital stream, out through the optical digital output on most Macs. This un-coded stream could be sent to the digital input of a 'home' receiver (or pro gear) to be de-coded and passed through to the 6ch analog outputs?